# Row-wise Interpolation in dataframe using interp1d

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, interpolation

I have the following dataframe (df) in python:

```
X1  X2  Y1  Y2  X   YInt
10  20  0.6 1   17  ???
5   50  0.4 1   9   ???
```

I'm trying to add a new column (YInt) to that dataframe, which evaluates the linearly-interpolated Y Value for a given X and the given coordinates X1,Y2, X2,Y2 in a given row.

So far I have the following code:

```
df['YInt'] = interp1d(df[['X1','X2']],df[['Y1','Y2']],bounds_error=False)(df['X'])
```

However, an error is reported that the Arrays don't equal in length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**See last edit**

You can apply the `interp1d` function to each row:

```
df['YInt'] = df.apply(lambda row:
                        interp1d([row.X1, row.X2],
                                 [row.Y1, row.Y2],
                                 bounds_error=False
                        )(row.X),
                        axis=1)
```

But this is quite slow on large dataframes, but I'm not sure how to optimize this.

---

Edit:
It's hard to optimize because you have to do row-wise operations. You should look into the [Enhancing Performance Guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html) in the Pandas docs to get a bit more insight. But anyway, using [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/jit-compilation.html#numba.vectorize) I managed to get a 4x performance increase with an approach similar to the one I gave before:

```
@numba.vectorize([numba.float64(numba.float64,  # Return type is float
                                numba.float64,  # with 5 float arguments
                                numba.float64,
                                numba.float64,
                                numba.float64)])
def interp_helper_numba(x1, x2, y1, y2, x):
    return interp1d([x1, x2], [y1, y2], bounds_error=False)(x)

df['Y'] = interp_helper_numba(df.X1.values, df.X2.values,
                              df.Y1.values, df.Y2.values,
                              df.X.values)
```

Pandas also has [`pd.Series.interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) function itself that wraps `scipy.interpolate.interp1d`, but if you want to use that you come across the same problem: you want to interpolate row-wise.

---

Edit:
Since this is just normal two-point linear interpolation, the values can be calculated manually really easily:

```
def manual_interp(x1, x2, y1, y2, x):
    return (y1 * (x2 - x) + y2 * (x - x1)) / (x2 - x1)


df['Y'] = manual_interp(df.X1.values, df.X2.values,
                        df.Y1.values, df.Y2.values,
                        df.X.values)
```

Tested it on a dataset with 100 million rows and it finishes in a second. :)

---

Final edit since Rolo wants a one-liner:

```
df['Y'] = (df.Y1.values * (df.X2.values - df.X.values) + df.Y2.values * (df.X.values - df.X1.values)) / (df.X2.values - df.X1.values)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. My df is unfortunately rather large and therefore this is way is rather slow. Is there a way to speed this calculation up?

Comment: Thanks Jurgy, The Interpolation calculation is quite easy, you're right. However I was still hoping to find a one-line-code solution that doesn't go through every row. Neither np.interp / interp1d / pd.interpolate seem to do this Job, or I haven't found a way to do it yet.

Comment: @Rolo, which is totally possible: `df['Y'] = (df.Y1.values * (df.X2.values - df.X.values) + df.Y2.values * (df.X.values - df.X1.values)) / (df.X2.values - df.X1.values)` but in my opinion less readable, but if that's what you want, be my guest ;)
And since you're new to SO, please mark my answer as 'answered' if it is satisfactory.

Comment: Thanks Jurgy! I think the latest Version is probably the one that I will use. Even if it's not the most readable.