# Pandas linearly interpolate row-wise

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

How can I linearly interpolate row-wise in a pandas dataframe, and append the results as a new column?

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"x1": [0, 0, 0], "x2": [10, 10, 10]})
display(df)
```

[image]

The columns contain the x-value which can be defined as `cols = [1,2]`

I want to interpolate at a value of x=1.1. The expected output is this:

[image]

I tried this, below, but received `ValueError: object of too small depth for desired array`

```
df["int"] = df.apply(lambda row: np.interp(cols, 1.1, row[df.columns.values]), axis=1)
```

Note that the actual `df` contains different numbers in each row and column; this example here is simple for proof of concept check. Also, there are 5000 columns and 200 rows in the real dataframe.

*Edit, Another Failed Attempt*

Based on the comment linking to [Row-wise Interpolation in dataframe using interp1d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47594932/row-wise-interpolation-in-dataframe-using-interp1d), I tried the following and received the same error.

```
cols = [1,2]
df["int"] = df.apply(lambda x: np.interp(cols, 1.1, df[list(df.columns)]), axis=1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Row-wise Interpolation in dataframe using interp1d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47594932/row-wise-interpolation-in-dataframe-using-interp1d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html):

```
cols = [1,2]

# save column names and set X values
old_cols = list(df.columns)+['int']
df = df.set_axis(cols, axis=1)
# add NaN column 
df[1.1] = np.nan
# interpolate using index and restore column names
df = (df.interpolate(method='index', axis=1)
        .set_axis(old_cols, axis=1)
      )
```

Output (modified example):

```
     x1    x2   int
0   0.0  10.0   1.0
1   0.0   5.0   0.5
2  10.0  20.0  11.0
```