# Linear interpolation along rows - single value per row - using pandas/scipy

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, interpolation

Supose I have the following pandas DataFrame

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[-10, -5, 0, 10], [17, 10, 16, 20], [40, 30, 10, -6]], columns=[0, 10, 20, 30])

>>> df.values
array([[-10,  -5,   0,  10],
       [ 17,  10,  16,  20],
       [ 40,  30,  10,  -6]])

>>> df.columns
Int64Index([0, 10, 20, 30], dtype='int64')
```

where the column names are the array of x that I want to interpolate on, and the values in the table are the y values. I want to perform a linear interpolation on each row with a single new_x in each row, i.e. where

```
new_x = [5, 15, 25]
```

I want to interpolate the value `5` using the column names as the x values and the first row as the y values, and so on down the rows with expected results `[-7.5, 13., 2.]`

I've tried the below

```
from scipy import interpolate
interpolate.interp1d(x=df.columns,y=df)(new_x)
```

but that gives

```
array([[-7.5, -2.5,  5. ],
       [13.5, 13. , 18. ],
       [35. , 20. ,  2. ]])
```

which is interpolating every element of new_x in each row. Instead I only want the diagonal from that result.

I can do it by applying an interpolate function over every row, but is there a more natural/faster single-line way that I'm missing?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47594932/row-wise-interpolation-in-dataframe-using-interp1d) asks something similar, but is only interpolating between 2 points.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to get the diagonal of your output with [`diag`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html):

```
import numpy as np

out = np.diag(interpolate.interp1d(x=df.columns,y=df)(new_x))
```

Output: `array([-7.5, 13. ,  2. ])`

Comment: My reticence in doing this approach is that it requires doing n^2 interpolations, rather than n, so will quickly become incredibly slow for big DataFrames

Comment: Then please clarity how you want to perform the interpolation? If you want to ignore the non-diagonal values, then the output should be different. Can you break down your calculations?

Comment: Is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocz4L.png) really what you want to do?

Comment: I want to only perform the interpolation for `5` (the first `new_x`) on `x=[0, 10, 20, 30]` and `y=[-10,  -5,   0,  10]` (the first row of the data frame), then interpolate `15` (the second value of `new_x`) on `x=[0, 10, 20, 30]` and `y=[ 17,  10,  16,  20]` (the second row of the data frame) and interpolate `25` (the third value of `new_x`) on `x=[0, 10, 20, 30]`  and `y=[ 40,  30,  10,  -6]` (the third row of the data frame)